# How to terminate while loop if character matched '.' in c

Tags: c, while-loop, char, printf, break

```
char b;
while((b=getchar()) != '.' );
{
   printf("%c",b);       
}
```

If I had the following input in stdin abcd.

it should print a then b then c then d then detect the . and terminate although its simply printing a . instead of abcd

Comment: what is it doing now...

Comment: it simply prints the . for some reason

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the semicolon at the end of while condition

Comment: THANK YOU wow I don't even know how I placed that their thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The semicolon at the end of the while loop makes it execute only once . It does not loop at all . Your program is simple a linear program with no looping .

Otherwise your program logic is fine .